# controlling keyboard input confirmation

Tags: unity, text-mesh-pro

I have an android app built from unity, and it uses a `Text Mesh Pro input field`. The problem I have is that, when the user wants to type in the input field, this sort of interface pops up:

[image]

So, the user has to click the input field, type his text, disable the keyboard by clicking somewhere on the screen and then press the `send` button in the app to send the message.

i.e. the keyboard overlays on top of the input field, so the user cannot press the send button after he's done typing?

How, do we make the keyboard appear like this?:

[image]
i.e. it slides in from beneath?